# Android TextView does not display russian symbols

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a txt file (UTF-8 format) saved at res/raw. When I try to display it's contents in a TextView in my app, I get rubbish instead of russian symbols.

Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my code:

```
package com.example.filereader_sample;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.content);
        try {
            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(file);
            String str = null;

            while ((str = dataIO.readLine()) != null)
                sBuffer.append(str + "\n");

            text.setText(sBuffer.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to display russian symbols correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, UTF-8 support for Android is incomplete. I think it's actually device-dependant if some of these symbols work.

Comment: Try adding this line (as the very first one) to your layout: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. It should tell the TextView to handle **UTF-8** characters properly